# Stop IIS-Site and all running sessions / applications

Tags: powershell, asp.net-core, iis, application-pool

I want to stop an IIS site, copy my new files / application to it, and then restart the site automated via PowerShell-script.

When I do this via IIS-Manager-GUI (right-click on site --> stop), everything works fine. The site is not reachable, all clients instantly loose their connection (SignalR is used). I replace my files and restart via GUI.

If I try the same with PowerShell Stop-IISSite, the site is not reachable for new requests, but the app seems to run on and existing clients keep working (kind of). If I try to copy my files, app files are still locked and cannot be replaced.

System is a Win2019 Nano Server with IIS 10.0 running an Asp.Net Core 3.1 application (process integrated AppPool).

Here is my PS-code:

```
  Stop-IISSite -Name siteToReplace -confirm:$False;
  Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Site siteToReplace is stopped, copy new files now..!';
  $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
  Start-IISSite -Name siteToReplace;
```

What am I missing here? Why does Stop-IISSite work differently than UI? How can I stop a site including running app instances to replace files without having to stop the whole IIS?

Comment: I think you can solve this by stopping the app pool instead. `Stop-WebAppPool`

Comment: `Stop-WebAppPool` is not in the iisadministration module. But I decided for: `$s=Get-IISSite -Name siteToReplace; $s.Stop();
(Get-IISAppPool -name $s.Applications[0].ApplicationPoolName).Recycle(); 
<# COPY #>;
$s.Start();`, which should do the trick, as long as the app pool is not used with other sites...

Comment: Because IIS Manager and the PowerShell cmdlets are not built upon the same foundation, their behaviors vary significantly like you fount out. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/iisadministration-powershell-cmdlets#iisadministration-overview

Answer (score 0):

So, after some research I used the Stop-Website command, after noticing other commands from the same WebAdministration list were working.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadminstration/stop-website?view=winserver2012-ps

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to install this module `Import-Module **IISAdministration**`

Then you can have list of sites

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-IISSite

Name             ID   State      Physical Path                  Bindings
----             --   -----      -------------                  --------
Default Web Site 1    Started    %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot  http *:80:
mangos           2    Started    E:\DotAng\Release              http *:8000:
                                                                http *:80:mango.com
banana           3    Started    E:\testapi\testApi\WebApplicat http *:8080:
                                 ion1
testapp.com      4    Started    E:\testapi\TestApiRelease      http *:800:testapp.com
Mango            5    Started    E:\testapi\TestApiRelease      http *:8001:
```

Stop specific website

```
Stop-IISSite -Name "Mango"
```

Starting specific website

```
Start-IISSite -Name "Mango"
```